# AutoEllipsis not working when set height on button with image

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a button

```
_BtnDump = new Button();
            _BtnDump.Name = "dum" + i;
            _BtnDump.Text = data.DumpName;
            _BtnDump.Width = 98;
            _BtnDump.Height = 52;
            //add icon dump puja
            _BtnDump.Image = Image.FromFile(@"Images\dump.ico");
            _BtnDump.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            _BtnDump.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.TextAboveImage;
            // Below code is not work yet. the layout get screwed
            //_BtnDump.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11); //new methode
            _BtnDump.Visible = true;
            _BtnDump.AutoSize = false;
            _BtnDump.AutoEllipsis = true;
            _BtnDump.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

when set height default 23 to 52, text change to multiline  and no display "..."

how to keep the text single line when height is set with AutoEllipsis?

i set the height because i have image under the text. so, when text multiline, the image is cropped.

[image]

**EDIT**

This is result image when use code from @dr.null.
the image now not cropped but the area of image is small between the text, so the image is pressed and the image always in bottom when use `TextImageRelation.ImageAboveText`
[image]

this is the button i want

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `Button` control by design does not provide much to dictate how the text should be formatted and rendered. Either, when the Gdi or Gdi+ method is used to render the string. The Gdi+ is used if the [`UseCompatibleTextRendering`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.usecompatibletextrendering?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) property is enabled. Both text formats have the word break flag.

While the default text rendering looks almost perfect to me, you still can -- if you want - change this behavior and have the text in a single line with trimming. For that, you need to derive a class from the `Button` control, override the `OnPaint` method to keep the button's visual style and draw each part at the right location and size. That requires calculating the bounds of each part (text, image, face, highlight....etc.) mainly, according to the values of the `Text`, `TextAlign`, `Image`, `ImageAlign`, `TextImageRelation`, `Font`, and some others.

Instead of doing all of that, I'll use `Reflection` here to get all the drawing requirements from the base, adapter, and relevant helper classes.

- The text and image bounds from [`LayoutOptions.LayoutData`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ButtonInternal/ButtonBaseAdapter.cs,1484) instance.
- The [`TextFormatFlags`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textformatflags?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) and [`StringFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) from the [`LayoutOptions.TextFormatFlags`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ButtonInternal/ButtonBaseAdapter.cs,938) and [`LayoutOptions.StringFormat`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ButtonInternal/ButtonBaseAdapter.cs,909) properties respectively.
- The [`PushButtonState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.pushbuttonstate?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.PushButtonState)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) from the [`DetermineState`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ButtonInternal/ButtonStandardAdapter.cs,31) method.

```cs
[DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class WordWrapButton : Button
{
    private bool _wordWrop = true;
    // false to enable the single line text...
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool WordWrap
    {
        get => _wordWrop;
        set
        {
            if (_wordWrop != value)
            {
                _wordWrop = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        if (WordWrap || FlatStyle != FlatStyle.Standard) return;

        LayoutData data = new LayoutData(this, e);

        ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(e.Graphics, ClientRectangle,
            string.Empty, Font, false, data.State);

        if (UseCompatibleTextRendering)
        {
            using (var br = new SolidBrush(Enabled
                ? ForeColor : SystemColors.GrayText))
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, br,
                    data.TextBounds, data.StringFormat);
        }
        else
        {
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, Font, data.TextBounds,
                Enabled ? ForeColor : SystemColors.GrayText, data.TextFormat);
        }

        if (Image != null)
        {
            if (Enabled)
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image, data.ImageBounds);
            else
            {
                ControlPaint.DrawImageDisabled(e.Graphics, Image,
                    data.ImageBounds.X, data.ImageBounds.Y, Color.Transparent);
            }
        }            
    }

    class LayoutData
    {
        public LayoutData(ButtonBase button, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            var pubFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;
            var nonPubFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
            var adapter = button.GetType()
                .GetProperty("Adapter", nonPubFlags)
                .GetValue(button);
            var layoutOptions = adapter.GetType()
                .GetMethod("Layout", nonPubFlags)
                .Invoke(adapter, new object[] { e });
            var layoutData = layoutOptions.GetType()
                .GetMethod("Layout", nonPubFlags)
                .Invoke(layoutOptions, null);

            Client = (Rectangle)layoutData.GetType()
                .GetField("client", nonPubFlags)
                .GetValue(layoutData);

            ImageBounds = (Rectangle)layoutData.GetType()
                .GetField("imageBounds", nonPubFlags)
                .GetValue(layoutData);

            TextBounds = (Rectangle)layoutData.GetType()
                .GetField("textBounds", nonPubFlags)
                .GetValue(layoutData);

            TextFormat = (TextFormatFlags)layoutOptions.GetType()
                .GetProperty("TextFormatFlags", pubFlags)
                .GetValue(layoutOptions);

            TextFormat &= ~TextFormatFlags.WordBreak;

            if (button.AutoEllipsis)
                TextFormat |= TextFormatFlags.WordEllipsis;

            StringFormat = (StringFormat)layoutOptions.GetType()
                .GetProperty("StringFormat", pubFlags)
                .GetValue(layoutOptions);

            StringFormat.FormatFlags |= StringFormatFlags.NoWrap;

            if (button.AutoEllipsis)
                StringFormat.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisWord;                

            State = (System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.PushButtonState)
                adapter.GetType()
                .GetMethod("DetermineState", nonPubFlags)
                .Invoke(adapter, new object[] { true });

            if (button.ClientRectangle.
                Contains(button.PointToClient(MousePosition)) &&
                MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
                State = System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.PushButtonState.Pressed;
        }

        public Rectangle Client { get; }
        public Rectangle TextBounds  { get; }
        public Rectangle ImageBounds { get; }
        public TextFormatFlags TextFormat { get; }
        public StringFormat StringFormat { get; }
        public System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.PushButtonState State { get; }
    }
}
```

[image: SO75694016]

---

Another example below for your specific requirement where:

- You have an Image to display below the text (since `TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.TextAboveImage`) and it shouldn't be clipped if its size is bigger than the available space. For that you need to call an `Graphics.DrawImage` method overload that takes both destination and source rectangles.
- The Text should be rendered in a single line with trimming if needed.
- Fill the button face with a color and keep the hover, press, focus effects.

```cs
// +
using VisualStyles = System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles;

[DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class WordWrapButton : Button
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var g = e.Graphics;
        var flags = TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter
            | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter;

        if (AutoEllipsis) flags |= TextFormatFlags.WordEllipsis;

        var recFocus = new Rectangle(4, 4, Width - 8, Height - 8);
        var recText = new Rectangle(recFocus.X, recFocus.Y, recFocus.Width,
            TextRenderer.MeasureText(g, Text, Font, recFocus.Size, flags).Height * 2);
        var recImage = new Rectangle(recFocus.X, recText.Bottom, recFocus.Width,
            recFocus.Bottom - recText.Bottom);
        var state = VisualStyles.PushButtonState.Normal;

        if (Enabled)
        {
            if (ClientRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(MousePosition)))
            {
                if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
                    state = VisualStyles.PushButtonState.Pressed;
                else
                    state = VisualStyles.PushButtonState.Hot;
            }
            else if (Focused)
            {
                state = VisualStyles.PushButtonState.Default;
            }
            else
            {
                recFocus.Inflate(1, 1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            state = VisualStyles.PushButtonState.Disabled;
            recFocus.Inflate(1, 1);
        }

        base.OnPaint(e);

        ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(g, ClientRectangle, state);

        using (var br = new SolidBrush(BackColor))
            g.FillRectangle(br, recFocus);

        TextRenderer.DrawText(g, Text, Font, recText, Enabled
            ? ForeColor : SystemColors.GrayText, flags);

        if (Image != null)
        {
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

            if (Enabled)
            {
                g.DrawImage(Image, recImage,
                    0, 0, Image.Width, Image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }
            else
            {
                var cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[][]
                {
                        new [] { 0.299f, 0.299f, 0.299f, 0f, 0f},
                        new [] { 0.587f, 0.587f, 0.587f, 0f, 0f},
                        new [] { 0.114f, 0.114f, 0.114f, 0f, 0f},
                        new [] { 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f},
                        new [] { 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f}
                });
                using (var att = new ImageAttributes())
                {
                    att.SetColorMatrix(cm, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);

                    g.DrawImage(Image, recImage, 0, 0, Image.Width, Image.Height,
                        GraphicsUnit.Pixel, att);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note, forgot to mention in my first post that, calling the `base.OnPaint(e);` is also necessary to show the ToolTip if the text is trimmed and the `AutoEllipsis` property is enabled.

[image: SO75694016B]

Comment: when i use youre code, i cant change the back color of button, and image still cropped in size 52, because a space between the text and image when autoellipsis. this is same space, when the autoellipsis is multiline in my case. @dr.null

Comment: @PujaSurya I see. Then keeping the visual style is not required here. Let me post another example based on your image. Shortly.

Comment: see my edit for the result. @dr.null

Comment: @PujaSurya Now the new image is new requirement. No `TextImageRelation.ImageAboveText` in your original post. You have here two different approaches. Study them, tweak them to get your satisfactory result. With the second example in particular, you can resize and reposition the text and image rectangles based on the `TextImageRelation` value. Good luck.

Comment: yes, no imageabovetext in my question but imageabovetext is a value in button. like your first image example code. the text could be place anywhere, like buton normally. but when the second code, the button text always on top. cannot place to bottom. when value imageabovetext.